# Android: Get initialization code to run every time user launches app

Tags: android

I have an app with a main activity (A) with menus, and separate activities (B, C, D) for the tasks selected from the menu. I have initialization code which is currently in onCreate(). But if the user leaves the app by pressing the home button, and then re-launches by tapping the app icon, onCreate() does not run. I cannot put the initialization code in onRestart(), as this runs when the user returns to the menu after a task run by say B. How can I get the code to run on every launch, but only on launch?

Comment: If `onCreate()` isn't called again, it's because the activity instance wasn't destroyed.  Therefore, whatever you need to initialize should still be initialized.

Comment: Yes, but things will have changed since it was first initialized. I need to get back to the starting state of the main activity when the user taps the app icon.

Comment: Why?  Android is purposefully designed not to work that way.  In fact, if A is your launcher activity and B is some other activity, and the user presses home while looking at B, the launcher icon will take them back to B, not A.  If A has been destroyed, it won't even be recreated until the user presses back.

Comment: This is certainly the default behaviour, but Android provides flags and attributes so that you can change it. For example with android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" and                android:launchMode="singleTask" set in the manifest for the main activity, if the user presses home from B, then the launcher icon takes them to A, not B, which is what I want. I also want a "clean" start. From the docs [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) it looks as though clearTaskOnLaunch ought to do this, but no joy

Comment: It does sound like `clearTaskOnLaunch` should solve part of the problem.  But even if it works as [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear) describe, the root activity still may or may not be recreated, and AFAIK there's no sanctioned way to distinguish resuming from the background vs. resuming from the backstack.  Possible hacky solution: make every activity that the root activity launches set a static flag in its `onBackPressed()`, and test and clear it in the root activity's `onResume()`.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand how the android life cycle works: 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

[image]

Basically, you need to run your code on `onResume` and `onStart` depending on what you want to achieve

---

**EDIT:**

Since the icon launches a `VIEW` intent, you could check for the intent when the application is resumed or restarted.

Comment: I have the life-cycle diagram, thanks, and I have been referring to it. onResume and onStart will both run when the user returns to A after finishing with B. This is not want I need.

Comment: Sorry, but while I do understand what you are asking now, it would help to know the motivation behind it. Perhaps this is not your actual problem, but one that arises from the solution you originally thought about.